# How do I make `go get` to build against x86_64 instead of i386

Tags: go

I am trying to use either go-qml or gotk3 to build a very simple desktop app that can run under OS X. However when I try to use `go get` to install either library, it will try to build for i386 and skip the libraries that were build against x86_64. I could try to get the 32 bit version of those libraries, but I would prefer to build for 64bit. How do I instruct go get to do so?

The warnings that are followed by errors look lie this:

```
go get gopkg.in/qml.v1
# gopkg.in/qml.v1
ld: warning: ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.2/lib/QtWidgets.framework/QtWidgets, file was built for x86_64 which       is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.2/lib/QtWidgets.framework/QtWidgetsignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.2/lib/QtGui.framework/QtGui, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.2/lib/QtGui.framework/QtGuiignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.2/lib/QtQuick.framework/QtQuick, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/Cellar/qt5/5.3.2/lib/QtQuick.framework/QtQuick
```

Comment: Set `$GOARCH=amd64` is the short answer.

Comment: A simple way is to get the `darwin-amd64` version of the Go distribution from https://golang.org/dl/ -- cross-compiling with `cgo` is also possible, but it looks like you can avoid it in this case.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks! That solved it! I wish I could accept your comment as the answer.

Comment: @ajmurmann How about this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the environment variable `GOARCH` to the value `amd64`. This instructs the `go` command to generate files for `amd64`. Other valid values for `GOARCH` include `386`, `arm`, `arm64`, and others.

Answer (score 1):

## F.Y.I.

> The Go compilers support the following instruction sets:
>
> - amd64, 386
>
>   - The x86 instruction set, 64- and 32-bit.
> - arm64, arm
>
>   - The ARM instruction set, 64-bit (AArch64) and 32-bit.
> - mips64, mips64le, mips, mipsle
>
>   - The MIPS instruction set, big- and little-endian, 64- and 32-bit.
> - ppc64, ppc64le
>
>   - The 64-bit PowerPC instruction set, big- and little-endian.
> - riscv64
>
>   - The 64-bit RISC-V instruction set.
> - s390x
>
>   - The IBM z/Architecture.
> - wasm
>
>   - [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org/).
>
> (from: [Introduction](https://golang.org/doc/install/source#introduction) | Installing Go from source | Doc @ golang.org)

Also, you can `go tool dist list` to check the available architectures to build in your machine.

```
$ go tool dist list
aix/ppc64
android/386
android/amd64
android/arm
android/arm64
darwin/amd64
darwin/arm64
dragonfly/amd64
freebsd/386
(* snip *)
```

To build a static binary for macOS (Intel/ARM64) would be as below. In this manner, I suppose `GOOS="darwin" GOARCH="arm64"` combination will be for `M1` architecture.

```sh
MyVar="foo"

CGO_ENABLED=0 \
        GOOS="darwin" \
        GOARCH="amd64" \
        GOARM="" \
        go build \
        -ldflags="-s -w -extldflags \"-static\" -X 'main.myVar=${MyVar}'" \
        -o="/path/to/export/bin/myApp" \
        "/path/to/main.go"
```

To compile for Linux on ARM v6, such as RaspberryPi Zero W, the combination would be as below.

```
$ CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS="linux" GOARCH="arm" GOARM="6" go build .
```